# Hide all warnings in IPython

Tags: python, warnings, ipython

I need to produce a screencast of an IPython session, and to avoid confusing viewers, I want to disable all warnings emitted by `warnings.warn` calls from different packages. Is there a way to configure the *ipythonrc* file to automatically disable all such warnings?

Answer (score 1236, accepted):

Place:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

inside `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/disable-warnings.py`.

Quite often it is useful to see a warning once. This can be set by:

```
warnings.filterwarnings(action='once')
```

Comment: Also works for IPython notebook warnings. Nice fix :)

Comment: @FrozenFlame, you change it back to 'default'

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

Comment: You can also execute this in the a notebook, in order to suppress only (certain) warnings in one specific notebook

Comment: Something odd happens to me, I work on Kaggle notebook, and even if I set `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')` at the beginning of my script, I get warnings anyway. Should it be related to the fact that I use TPU accelerator, does TPU have a particular behaviour in this case ... I wonder. I do not understand.

Comment: works like butter!

Comment: Just make sure to invoke at the beginning of the code!

Comment: Same in Google Colab as well.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Even after including the warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') at the very beginning of the jupyter notebook in its own cell, warnings still get printed in the cell console

Answer (score 65):

I hide the warnings in the pink boxes by running the following code in a cell:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''<script>
code_show_err=false; 
function code_toggle_err() {
 if (code_show_err){
 $('div.output_stderr').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.output_stderr').show();
 }
 code_show_err = !code_show_err
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle_err);
</script>
To toggle on/off output_stderr, click <a href="javascript:code_toggle_err()">here</a>.''')
```

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer does not work in Jupyter (at least when using some libraries).

The JavaScript solutions here only hide warnings that are already showing but not warnings that would be shown in the future.

To hide/unhide warnings in Jupyter and [JupyterLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook_Applications) I wrote the following script that essentially toggles CSS to hide/unhide warnings.

```
%%javascript
(function(on) {
    const e = $("<a>Setup failed</a>");
    const ns = "js_jupyter_suppress_warnings";
    var cssrules = $("#" + ns);
    if(!cssrules.length)
        cssrules = $("<style id='" + ns + "' type='text/css'>div.output_stderr { } </style>").appendTo("head");
    e.click(function() {
        var s = 'Showing';
        cssrules.empty()
        if(on) {
            s = 'Hiding';
            cssrules.append("div.output_stderr, div[data-mime-type*='.stderr'] { display:none; }");
        }
        e.text(s + ' warnings (click to toggle)');
        on = !on;
    }).click();
    $(element).append(e);
})(true);
```

Comment: I receive the error "Javescript Error: $ is not defined"

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I'm getting the same error as Ben (I'm using JupyterLab).

Comment: It worked for me both in Jupyter and in JupyterLab. there may be some problem with your installation.

Comment: Works for me, but this also removes any other output generated in the cell.

Comment: Just look at the officially selected answer using `warnings`. This is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 5):

For [JupyterLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook_Applications), this should work (@Alasja):

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script>
var code_show_err = false;
var code_toggle_err = function() {
    var stderrNodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-mime-type="application/vnd.jupyter.stderr"]')
    var stderr = Array.from(stderrNodes)
    if (code_show_err){
        stderr.forEach(ele => ele.style.display = 'block');
    } else {
        stderr.forEach(ele => ele.style.display = 'none');
    }
    code_show_err = !code_show_err
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', code_toggle_err);
</script>
To toggle on/off output_stderr, click <a onclick="javascript:code_toggle_err()">here</a>.''')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the category otherwise even with the top solution above you'd get warnings

```
   warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```