# ipython - disable welcome message

Tags: ipython

Everytime i enter into `ipython` mode, ipython welcomes me with this message,

```
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter 
problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Greeting people is all good and well but it takes up most of my shell screen and i am made to do `clean` to remove them.

How can i disable this welcome message via configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
ipython console
```

You'll get it, if that's what you want.

Comment: Really? What version of ipython are you using?

Comment: IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Comment: Wow...that's kind of old, man. I'm using IPython 3.0.0. Perhaps you should consider upgrading it.

Comment: it worked, man thanks.but `WARNING` statements didn't go away. one can fix it using this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
ipython --no-banner
```

or set in configuration file

```
c.TerminalIPythonApp.display_banner = False
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Editing the IPython config file

Edit your config file and add

```
c.TerminalIPythonApp.display_banner = False
```

The *default profile's* config file is found at `/home/<user>/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

> The documentation for IPython configuration can be found [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html)

### Updating default profile

Create new config file if it does not exist, or use

```sh
ipython locate profile
```

to view the current profile location.