# Ignore pandas warnings

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

There are [some similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9031783/647991), but the replies there do not work for me.

I am trying to do this, as explained in the [warnings documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/warnings.html):

```
def disable_pandas_warnings():
    import warnings
    warnings.resetwarnings()  # Maybe somebody else is messing with the warnings system?
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')  # Ignore everything
    # ignore everything does not work: ignore specific messages, using regex
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.*')
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance*')
```

And I call this at the start of my test/program:

```
disable_pandas_warnings()
```

As you can see in the comments, I have:

- made sure that the warnings filters are not polluted (since filtering is performed on a first-match way)
- ignore all messages
- ignore specific messages (by giving message regex)

Nothing seems to work: messages are still displayed. How can I disable all warnings?

Comment: Can you add a mcve (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which triggers an unexpected warning?

Comment: @Goyo: I'll try. The code triggering the warnings is pretty big (and not written by me), but I'll try to extract an mcve

Comment: Can you please post the MCVE?