# turn warning off in a cell jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, jupyter-notebook

I get some useless warnings in python 3 jupyter notebook. I want to turn off these warnings in a particular cell only, so not in the rest of the ipynb-file.
Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: You can temporarily turn off all Python warnings with the [catch_warnings()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) context manager.

Comment: Does this answer work for you? Using this line `warnings.filterwarnings(action='once')` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9031848/4538920

Comment: "*I want to turn off these warnings in a particular cell only*": Unless you have a single instruction in the cell, you may want to disable warnings for *some* instructions, not for the *cell*.

Answer (score 36):

Write `%%capture` as the first line of the cell to catch cell output. You can use the options `--no-stderr`, `--no-stdout`, `--no-display`, and `--output` to control which cell outputs will be caught. See more details [here.](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=capture#cellmagic-capture)

Comment: This supresses all output from the cell not just warnings.

Comment: FWIW to answer the question directly, adding `%%capture output` at the top of the cell in Jupyter notebook seemed to work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, unfortunately

Comment: @glmorous are you using jupyter in vscode or some other ide?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, it's vscode.

Comment: @glmorous that's probably why the commands don't work. I don't think all standard Jupyter magic commands work in vscode.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, oh, I didn't know that.  Since some do work, I guess I thought that they all work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

**Solutions**:

Usually there is no need to extend the effect to the whole cell, as this may hide some other useful message, so use a context manager to ignore the warnings:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    # Your problematic instruction(s) here
```

If there are good reasons to protect the whole cell then simply prevent the *stderr* stream to be displayed in the cell output area by inserting the [capture](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=capture#cellmagic-capture) "magic":

```
%%capture --no-stderr
```

at the top of the cell (rather than indenting all lines).

---

**Explanations**:

The most logical way is to insert the code triggering a warning within a context manager introduced by keyword `with`. It switches off and restore the warning system prior and after the problematic code

Python provides such context manager as [`warnings.catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#available-context-managers):

> A context manager that copies and, upon exit, restores the
> warnings filter and the `showwarning()` function. If the
> `record` argument is `False` (the default) the context manager
> returns `None` on entry. If `record` is `True`, a list is
> returned that is progressively populated with objects as seen by
> a custom `showwarning()` function (which also suppresses output
> to `sys.stdout`).

You also need to register a *filter* to react to each warning captured by the context manager, else the *default filter* remains active.

Python provides the [`warnings.simplefilter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) which:

> Insert a simple entry into the list of warnings filter
> specifications

It registers some action (`ignore` for no action, `always` to print the warning message, etc, see [full description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter)).

Example:

```
import warnings, math
import numpy as np

# We want to compute the logs of this sequence.
# But log isn't defined for values <= 0
s = [-1, 5, 2, 0]

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    r = np.log(s)

print(r)
```

Comment: Note that with `%%capture`, the param `--no-stderr`  means to **not prevent** stderr from output (rather, everything else).

Answer (score 10):

Normally I want to keep stdout open for printing so I find using `catch_warnings` like this better:

```
import warnings

def action_with_warnings():
    warnings.warn("should not appear")

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True):
    action_with_warnings()
```

It has the disadvantage of storing the warnings in memory, but it is normally not a significant overhead and worth the simplicity. Even within a single cell I find having fine grained control means warnings I do care about are not accidentlly missed.

Answer (score 3):

I tried many different commands, but this one works for me

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

For me these two lines do the job:

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `%%capture --no-stdout` as the first line of the cell. That worked for me. Strangely, `%%capture --no-stderr` showed only the warnings, but none of the desired output.