# BackTrader graph plots in Jupiter notebook disappear when re-running cell

Tags: python, plot, graph, jupyter-notebook

I am using BackTrader for backtesting (using python3 in Jupiter Notebook on a Mac), and have used the following example from their documentation found at https://www.backtrader.com/docu/plotting/plotting.html:

```
import backtrader as bt

class Ind(bt.Strategy):

    def __init__(self):

        self.sma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.data)

datapath = 'CSV file on my computer.txt'  

data = bt.feeds.BacktraderCSVData(dataname = datapath)

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.addstrategy(Ind)
cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot()
```

When I plot a graph using BackTrader's cerebro.plot() function, it works fine the first time (see picture 1). [First time plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXX9x.png)

However, when I re-run the cell again (to tweak inputs), it disappears and is just left with the figure size output at the bottom (see picture 2). [Output after re-running cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yH8N.png)

It still doesn't work if I copy and paste the code in a new cell below and run it. I am still just left with the figure size output at the bottom.

This is very frustrating as every time I want to reproduce one of their plots, I am having to restart Jupiter notebook to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Additional info: I have also had the same problem when using the standard python debugger in Jupiter notebook

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same problem, I believe it it related to backtrader's interactions with matplotlib. I was able to fix it by including the line

```
%matplotlib inline
```

at the very top of my notebook (being right at the very top seems to be important, [as noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-matplotlib-plot-inline)). I did **NOT** need to include statements like `import matplotlib`.

This generates a system warning message each time a plot is generated, these can be suppressed using

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

as noted [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython).

**Minimal failing repro of the op's issue:**

In [1]:

```
import backtrader as bt
import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

    data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(
        dataname='AAPL',
        fromdate=datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1),
        todate=datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 31),
        reverse=False)

    cerebro.adddata(data)
    cerebro.run()
    cerebro.plot(style='bar')
```

In [2]:

```
cerebro.plot(style='bar')
```

**Fixed version of minimal failing repro:**

In [1]:

```
%matplotlib inline

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import backtrader as bt
import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

    data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(
        dataname='AAPL',
        fromdate=datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1),
        todate=datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 31),
        reverse=False)

    cerebro.adddata(data)
    cerebro.run()
    cerebro.plot(style='bar')
```

In [2]:

```
cerebro.plot(style='bar')
```