# Suppress error message during reading of file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I am reading a text file using `pandas.read_csv`. A small example of the file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P8RYJAOWT7LLMkmV_VX_nJk85uslzyKx). Below, is the way in which I am reading the file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', error_bad_lines=False, sep=r'\t+', header=None, dtype='|U', engine='python')
```

I am able to read the file properly and do all work. But, I keep getting messages like the ones shown below, and I will like to ignore them.

> Skipping line 689: Expected 81 fields in line 689, saw 265. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

There are hundreds of such lines (for different line numbers). I have already tried the answer for hiding of warnings shown in [here (Hide all warnings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython/9031848#9031848). Unfortunately, it does not work. Also, I will like to **suppress (not show) only the specific kind of error messages that I have mentioned in this post** (`Skipping line ... delimiter is used.`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use argument *warn_bad_lines=False*:

```
pd.read_csv(error_bad_lines=True, warn_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.