# Spyder - disable warnings inside Spyder Console

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I use Spyder (4.1.5) as my python editor. When I run the code it shows a million workings that make it impossible for me to really focus on the output of the code. I read a lot of posts here on stackoverflow (see for example: [Hide all warnings in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython) ) and it seems  they all suggest to add

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

This for sure does not work.

For example, one of the many warnings printed to console many times is this one:

```
C:\...\Utils.py:2831: FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.
```

However, I also have this line of code at the very beginning of the script:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
```

Still, no luck in disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

worked for me using Spyder 5 and Python 3.8.10