# TQDM progress_apply error on import in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, tqdm

I am using TQDM's ***progress_apply*** function in Jupyter notebook, but get a future warning (as below) when importing the module using:

```
from tqdm.notebook 
import tqdm tqdm.pandas()
```

**future Warning**
*....\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py:697: FutureWarning:
The Panel class is removed from pandas. Accessing it from the top-level namespace will also be removed in the next version*

How would I correct my code to future proof this?

Answer (score 2):

`tqdm` has a especial wrapper for `pandas` and the maintainers of `tqdm` need to watch any API changes done to new releases of `pandas`, and make adjustments for any breaking changes.

This particular warning means that - `pandas` removed a class called *Panel* and you should not be using this class from the `tqdm` wrapper.

If you want to avoid seeing this warning, you can suppress it by following the discussion in this thread [Hide all warnings in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython)

Also, this warning message is version specific and it would help people if you update the version of `tqdm` and `pandas` you are getting this warning with.