# Config IPython show warning once

Tags: ipython

I'm trying to config IPython show warning message once with module warnings, the simple code as below

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('once', RuntimeWarning)
def x()
    warnings.warn('xxx', RuntimeWarning)
x()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\ipython:2: RuntimeWarning: xx
x()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\ipython:2: RuntimeWarning: xx
```

as you can see the warning always show, if I use warning.simplefilter('ignore', RuntimeWarning) then the warning message will be hide. and also tried in python terminal, it work as expected.

so is IPython doesn't support show warning message once? or is there anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you run `x()` twice in two cells or `x();x()` once in one cell?

Comment: I ran x() twice

Comment: If you run `x();x()` in once cell, do you see one or two warnings?

Comment: if I use x();x()  then will see one waring
x();x()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\ipython:2: RuntimeWarning: xxx
but if I ran the command again still get the same waring message
x();x()
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\ipython:2: RuntimeWarning: xxx
according to the document, there should no warning output

Comment: Running a separate cell is like running a separate program. Running a pure python REPL is like executing one program step by step. That's why you see the warning each time you execute a cell but only once in REPL.

Comment: thanks Vitalizzare, is possible config ipython behavior like python REPL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9031848/14909621

Comment: I tried this before and doesn't work, so I post this one