# Supress Tensorflow warnings within jupyter notebook cell in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tf.keras, suppress-warnings

I want to remove all warnings from pythons tensorflow==2.8 .

I do imports like this

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

I try the following, but nothing of these methods keep Warnings or Infos out of my results' cell.

**modify the option parameters**

```
tensorflow.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tensorflow.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
tensorflow.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' # 2 is for Info and Warnings, 3 is everything
```

**notebook magic**

- Try to use `%%capture` at the beginning of a cell
- Try to use `;` at the end of a line

**with statements**

```
from IPython.utils import io

    with io.capture_output() as captured:
        #Function to use where output should disappear
```

**from @Usama Aleem**

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

One of the Warnings:

> WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as
> lstm_cell_layer_call_fn,
> lstm_cell_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses while saving
> (showing 2 of 2). These functions will not be directly callable after
> loading.

Answer (score 1):

you can ignore or hide all the warnings in ipython file by using this code

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: For me, it does not help.

Comment: you can refer to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython