# Remove red highlighted text from Jupyter notebook from an API call

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do I remove the red highlighted text in Jupyter Notebook which relays the whole API request information when called?

[image]

I have tried

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide all warnings in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython)

Comment: @tbhaxor Which part of the solution? I have tried the 'warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')' in the notebook to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Increase `c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 1000000`

to `c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 100000000`

in the `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file. You may have to create this file if you cannot find it.

[Note this works for the first couple times but not after that -- change numbers??]

Answer (score 0):

You can run jupyter with the following arguments:
jupyter-notebook --NotebookApp.max_buffer_size=40000000000  --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000000

Comment: This worked initially but after subsequent runs it didn't remove the red 'warnings'. Is it worth increasing the numbers?

Comment: depends on the errors, buddy.